# How I use foreach to build 2 different columns in php, pdo

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I just copy and paste, and then modify the code, it works fine to build a select.

```
$sql_company_list = "SELECT Company FROM company_view";

$data = $db->build_select($sql_company_list);

public function build_select($sql){

    $data = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $data->execute();
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $option = "";
    $count = 1;

    foreach($data as $row){

        foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
            $option .= "<option value=".$count;         
            $option .= ">";
            $option .= "".$value."";
            $option .= "</option>";
        }   
    $count++;
    }           
    return $option;
}
```

But, when I wish to select id and company as option value (id) and option name (company), it don't work. How to make minimal changes to do it? Many thanks.

```
$sql_company_list = "SELECT id, Company FROM company_view";

$data = $db->build_select_1($sql_company_list);

public function build_select_1($sql){

    $data = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $data->execute();
    $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // i don't exactly understand... 

    $option = "";
    //$count = 1;

    foreach($data as $row){

        foreach ($row){ // this don't work
            $option .= "<option value=".$row[0]; 
            // i wish to do this e.g. value assigns to ID           
            $option .= ">";
            $option .= "".$row[1]."";
            // i wish to do this e.g. option name assigns to company    
            $option .= "</option>";
        }   
    //$count++;
    }           
    return $option;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your working code,

```
    foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
        $option .= "<option value=".$count;         
        $option .= ">";
        $option .= "".$value."";
        $option .= "</option>";
    }
```

This is working correctly for you. So for setting name and value of company to dropdown options, you can modify your code as below.

Instead of `$row[0]` and `$row[1]`, use it the below way

```
    foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
        $option .= "<option value=".$value;         
        $option .= ">";
        $option .= "".$name."";
        $option .= "</option>";
    }
```

Try it and see if it works for you.